# Now I have following code in shell script, can someone help me fix it and understand the code?

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell script as well as new to stackoverflow. :) and I need some help from you guys

```
cat Header_list.txt
ID

cat test123123.csv
Name              ID           Portfolio CounterParty Cards ID  Process *Theoretical Model  Issue Date
MUREX_01576184  :MUREX_01576184 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  4/27/2016
MUREX_01576194  :MUREX_01576194 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  4/27/2016
MUREX_02351193  :MUREX_02351193 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  10/31/2016
MUREX_02351197  :MUREX_02351197 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  10/31/2016
MUREX_02351203  :MUREX_02351203 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  10/31/2016
MUREX_02351207  :MUREX_02351207 :HK-AUFWD   H-CCBC_PM   20229   metals  :BNS Forex  10/31/2016



# here is the main code
awk 'NR==FNR{
            Cols=Cols (Cols?"|":"")$1
            next
        }

 FNR==1{
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
            if (match($i,Cols)) 
            Ar[++n]=i
       }

       {
           for (i=1;i<=n;i++) 
           printf (i<n)? $(Ar[i])  FS : $(Ar[i])
           printf "\n"
        }' FS=","  Header_list.txt test123123.csv

Expected Output:
ID
:MUREX_01576184
:MUREX_01576194
:MUREX_02351193
:MUREX_02351197
:MUREX_02351203
:MUREX_02351207

Actual 
 ID             Cards ID
:MUREX_01576184 20229
:MUREX_01576194 20229
:MUREX_02351193 20229
:MUREX_02351197 20229
:MUREX_02351203 20229
:MUREX_02351207 20229
```

In the example, it returns all the columns which the header contains "ID". I am thinking it's the NR==FNR part causing the problem. But I couldn't understand what it means by

```
 Cols=Cols (Cols?"|":"")$1
 next
```

Could someone help me understand the code? If possible, fix the code too?

Comment: wrap that `Cols=..` code with a debugging statement, so you can see how the values change, i.e. `print "#dbg A.Cols="cols;Cols=Cols...;print "#dbg B.Cols=Cols"` It looks like  you're really just printing the 2nd field appended with a `:`, so consider `awk '{print ":" $2}' dataFile`. You can add the header in a separate step (or are this example files that are much simpler than your real case?). Good luck.

Comment: Hi shelter, thank you for your help. The actual file contains 600+ columns and basically I want to select the entire column based on my input value, which is a variable.I tried many solutions, but none of them works. I am frustrated now

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the quoting right on my dbg code. try `print "#dbg: A.Cols="Cols; Cols=Cols... ; print "#dbg: B.Cols=" Cols` ; How many columns are you trying to extract from your 600? Your output is very unusual, If MS Windows was involved in creating any of the files and you now using unix to process, remove the `\r` lineendings by running `dos2unix file1 file2 file....n` (each file in the list is processed). Good luck.

Comment: I am trying to extract only 4 including $1, $2, $3 and $variable. so the pain is really about the variable part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a `match` method that takes a regex as a second argument.

Change this if to normal comparison (`==`) should help.

Comment: It works! However, I have a follow-up question. if the value in the Header_list file has more than 3 space (i.e. Cards ID A), the code returns error as the following                                                              awk: cmd. line:14: (FILENAME=test123123.csv FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `Cards ID A'
             ^ ran out for this one
Is there any way to resolve the string format problem? I tried put ' ' in the header_list file, but it will return nothing.

Comment: sorry, it should be if i have 7 space in my value, not 3.